# Check Login in MasterPage before ANY other code is processed VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, master-pages

I'm developing an application which requires log in.

I'm using Master Pages and a customer Web Control which is my main menu system.

The main menu accesses database information to provide notifications and various things, none of which will work unless the user is logged in.

I am trying to place the following code:

```
If Session("hgAdminUser") = "" And InStr(Request.ServerVariables("url"), "/Login.aspx") <= 0 Then _
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx") ' if userSession is empty, redirect to login page.
```

Into the top of my MasterPage code behind, but it's still trying to process scripts, the main problem being that it is running the .ascs file which requires Database access, which it can't do without the required parameters from Login.

I've tried running it within a Page_PreInit sub, also Page_Load and Page_Init, but in all cases it ignores this (or probably doesn't ignore it, but errors come in before it deals with this) and returns a big fat ERROR due to functions that I don't even want it to be running!!

So basically, my question is, how can I check for a session variable, which if not present cause all other scripts on the page to be ignored and redirect?

This is all using VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

You have to design separate master page for `public` content pages and `secure` content pages.

You may write following code in the handler of  PreInit or Load event of `secure` master page.

```
If IsNothing(Session("hgAdminUser")) Then
   Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
End If
```

Comment: How does a secure masterpage differ then? In effect, the only "public" page is the log in page. Sorry, I'm a complete newby to .net

Comment: secure content pages are requested by the valid user (authenticate).